# SQL Order by clause not returning in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am running a query in MySQLWorkbench using an order by clause and my return table is not in alphabetical order. My query is:

```
SELECT property_value FROM job_shared_context
WHERE property_key = "case-name"
Order BY property_value asc
```

My return table:

```
"cqroneponv;,'c"
"padding Case"
"pwTest1"
"pwTest5"
"test 1"
"test 1"
"Test Case 12"
"Test Case 2"
"test"
"test"
"Test1"
"Turtle Case"
```

I assume the test in lines 9 and 10 would be between "pwTest5" and "test 1" for alphabetical order.

Comment: That looks to be in alphabetical order to me, for case insensitive. Instead of telling us line numbers can you be clear what you think is incorrect here? Also, which DBMS? mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Is it possible the instances of just "test" (not sure why you couldn't just point out the words) have non-printing characters in them?

Comment: @SeanLange mysql. From my assumption of alphabetical order is should be ordered "cqroneponv;,'c" > "padding Case" > "pwTest1" > "pwTest5" > "test" > "test" > "test 1" > "test 1" > "Test Case 12" > "Test Case 2" > "Test1" > "Turtle Case"

Comment: @Uueerdo No the quote closes it off so there are trailing spaces or anything

Comment: @LeePruissen Hence me specifying "non-printing", they wouldn't show up. Add `LENGTH(property_value)` to your select to see if "test" is 4 characters long.

Comment: @Uueerdo "Test" returns value 6 because of the two quotes. "Test 1" returns a value of 8

Comment: Ah, that answers it, the quotes are IN your string values; `"` probably sorts after space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have quotes, or any other non-alphanumeric symbols in your strings, they will be included in the sorting calculations. It is obvious with things like spaces, dashes, etc...

To specifically ignore them in your query, something like this should work:

`ORDER BY TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM property_value)`

Of course, you can trim multiple characters by nesting TRIM calls like so:

`ORDER BY TRIM(BOTH '_' FROM TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM property_value))`